# How to round off a date in PostgreSQL to end date of preceding month or next month?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date type column called "raw_date". I need to derive another date column from it with the logic being-

1) If day in "raw_date" is between 1 to 14 then derived date should be last date of preceding month(so, if preceding month is in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) last date will be 31 ; if preceding month is in (4,6,9,11) last date will be 30 ; **if preceding month is in (2) & year is leap year , last date will be 29 and if it's non-leap year then it will be 28**

2) Also, I need to factor in year changes. Suppose, if "raw_date" = '2020-01-12' , derived date will be '2019-12-31'

I am trying to use 'case' statement and supplying explicit last month dates but there are many scenarios so not able to cover all scenarios required as per logic. 
Can there be a code which covers all scenarios including leap year & year changes if date is between 1 to 14 in January.

Comment: Presumably, you want the last day of the current month for other days in the month.  You should mention that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
(case when extract(day from raw_date) <= 14
      then date_trunc('month', raw_date) - interval '1 day'
      else date_trunc('month', raw_date) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
 end)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ba8d06ad8f111f45b24e255cbead5df6) is a db<>fiddle.